# How to remove fonts in Ubuntu?

Tags: 13.10, 64-bit, uninstall, fonts

I installed Garamond font in Ubuntu 13.10. Now I cannot remove the font. I cannot find it anywhere.

I have tried the following and all failed:

1. font-manager application
2. search font in `usr/share/fonts` and `home/.fonts` or `usr/share/local/fonts`
3. searcing name of fonts

But I can still see the font in libreoffice. Where are the fonts gone?

Comment: Can you open a terminal and type `locate -i garamond`? This would give you the locations of all file paths with "garamond" in them ;-).

Comment: Can you tell us how you installed it?

Answer (score 8):

User-installed fonts are stored in `$HOME/.local/share/fonts/`. Just delete the unwanted files in there.